# RadAsyncUpload Maximum File Size

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I have been asked to write an application that basically moves files from a source (USB, CD) to a centralized location.  Initially this application will be for internal use only but in the future may be needed by remote users.  The files I need to move can be in excess of 4-5Gb.  It has been suggested I use the Telerik RadAsyncUpload component.  Can anyone tell me if I am likely to run into problems trying to upload files of this size using this control?

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/upload-uploading-large-files.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow larger uploads the maxRexquestLength and executionTimeout needs to be added to your web.config:

```
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="5242880" executionTimeout="10800" />
    </system.web>
```

The trickiest part of having this work is that the execution timeout may exceed the upload time required. So set it higher based on your average users bandwidth. We monitor this by logging when the execution timeout occurs and adjusting as needed periodically. Since your app will be internally initially this probably won't be an issue at all if they are transferring over the LAN.

Further info on this is available in the Telerik documentation [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/upload-uploading-large-files.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 parts on setting the size of the file that could be uploaded through RadAsyncUpload:
1) Setting the file size in the telerik control

```
<system.webServer>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="100000000" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

2)Configures ASP.NET HTTP runtime settings, to allow the http Request message to be able to include your file. Here we need to set the maxRequestLength and executionTimeout accordingly.

```
<system.web><httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="2147483647" /></system.web>
```

3)IIS server would generally allow only 30MB of file to be uploaded. To be able to upload larger files, we need to make some other settings in the web.config , to increase the request limits.

```
<system.webServer>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="100000000" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```